# c# client is trying to send information rather than listen, why is this happening?

Tags: c#, .net, server, tcp, client

So I am writing a c# client server program where the client receives information from the server, however the client appears to try to send information rather than receive after the successfully connect

```
public void SL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
        tcpclnt.Connect(RecieveIP.Text, 8001); // use the ipaddress as in the server program

        MessageBox.Show("Connected");
        
        String str = Console.ReadLine();
        Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();
       
        ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] ba = asen.GetBytes(str);
        MessageBox.Show("Listening for information......");

        stm.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);

        byte[] bb = new byte[100];
        int k = stm.Read(bb, 0, 100);

        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(bb[i]));
            
        string toattk = str.ToString();
```

I think this, as the client and server do successfully connect, but the the message sent from the server is never actually recieved.

Server code for action when it connects and sends the message to the other computer:

```
private void Connectnattk_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse(ipv4.Text); //use local m/c IP address, and use the same in the client

        /* Initializes the Listener */
        TcpListener myList = new TcpListener(ipAd, 8001);

        /* Start Listeneting at the specified port */
        myList.Start();

        MessageBox.Show("The server is running at port 8001...");
        MessageBox.Show("The local End point is  :" + myList.LocalEndpoint);
        MessageBox.Show("Looking for other computer");

        Socket s = myList.AcceptSocket();
        Console.WriteLine("Found buddy " + s.RemoteEndPoint);

        ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
        s.Send(asen.GetBytes(satt.Text));
        MessageBox.Show("The command " + satt.Text + " was sent to the computer with IP address " + ipv4.Text);

        byte[] b = new byte[100];
        int k = s.Receive(b);
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(b[i]));

        /* clean up */

        s.Close();
        myList.Stop();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Could not find other computer.");
    }
```

They connect no problem, but the message sent from the server never appears on the client. I surmise this is because the client is trying to send a response back rather than receiving the message sent by the server. Or are there other reasons why the message is not received despite the computers connected? Thank you.

Comment: So both ends attempt to write something, then read whatever was sent by the other party? Note that while the OS has a transmit buffer, a write call will block once that buffer is full, until the client reads from their end. So by having both parties attempting to write first, you may be triggering a deadlock. Either your communication should take turns in a well defined order, or you should start multiple threads or async tasks to read and write simultaneously.

Comment: In SL_Click you're using `TcpStream`, but in DoWork you're using `Socket.Receive()`. Don't mix the APIs like that until you know what you're doing. Either use sockets OR `TcpListener`/`TcpClient`, not both. I suggest you do an `myList.AcceptTcpClient()' instead of 'AcceptSocket', then you can get the Stream from it.

Comment: I also think there is a string mixup, the client may be receiving the message from the server but not acting on it...

Comment: I tried using MessageBox.Show after string toattk so that it would popup with what is recieved, it shows byte [] as received, so for some reason the byte is not being decoded. Thanks.

Comment: *the client appears to try to send information* - *`stm.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);`* - C# only does what you tell it to?

Comment: Yes, I am wanting to reverse it so that the client recieves information rather than sends it. Thanks